# Bindingsource datagridview click fill data in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have a `datagridview` which is bind from a `bindingsource` I really try to find out how onclick row on `datagridview` the row data fill in the TextBox. Because I want to show some data on combobox according selection on datagridview. My code for bind the datagridview  is below

```
private void FillGrid()
{
    if (_fisComp == null)
        _fisComp = new FiscalComponent();

    List<FiscalPeriod> _fisPeriod = _fisComp.GetAllByFiscalPeriod(Convert.ToString(fiscalYearComboBox.SelectedValue));

    fiscalPeriodBindingSource.DataSource = _fisPeriod;
    fiscalPeriodDataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

I am binding my datagridview by list<> type . The problem is that I am getting data from my stored procedure `Y~`N` and i want to display in combobox in Yes or No

This code is where I am binding my combobox

```
    public void FillDropdown()
    {

        var itemsleaverun = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            itemsleaverun.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Y", "Yes"));
            itemsleaverun.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("N", "No"));
            leaveRunTypeComboBox.DataSource = itemsleaverun;
            leaveRunTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
            leaveRunTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
            leaveRunTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
     }
```

Comment: What is your underlying `DataSource`? a `DataTable` or some collection of items which are type of some class having some `Properties`? You need to specify it more. Your problem is very simple.

Comment: @KingKing i have edited my question please take a look

Comment: I want to mean your `DataGridView` DataSource, you want to bind one of it's DataSource members to a `TextBox`, so you have to know through that DataSource

Comment: @KingKing my datagridview is directly bind from  `fiscalPeriodBindingSource`. And i want to bind one value to `combobox`. Thanks

Comment: and yes I know but what is the underlying datasource of `fiscalPeriodBindingSource`? for example, if it's a `DataTable`, we will have `fiscalPeriodBindingSource = new BindingSource(yourDataTable,"");` and what member of that DataTable you want to bind to your combobox?

Comment: Ah, I can see it is the `List` of `FiscalPeriod` so what about `FiscalPeriod`, what properties does it has? And which one do you want to bind to your combobox?

Comment: @KingKing there are many properties on properties is `[DataMember]
        public int TaxMonth
        {
            get { return _taxMonth; }
            set
            {
                _taxMonth = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TaxMonth");
            }
        }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31581/discussion-between-abhishek-and-king-king)

Answer (score 0):

To bind one of the properties of `FiscalPeriod` to your combobox. I suppose you want to bind the Property `X` which can have values `"Yes"` or `"No"`. You can bind it to your combobox like this:

```
yourComboBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", fiscalPeriodBindingSource, "X");
```

The Property `X` should be able to have values which are contained in the Items list of your comboBox. Because your combobox has a DataSource, they should be contained in the values list for the DataSource `DisplayMember`.

Comment: in the Form constructor or Form load. The matter is the `fiscalPeriodBindingSource` and `yourComboBox` should be recognized as `declared` and your `fiscalPeriodBindingSource` should already be filled with data before.